# Get label of slider to move with slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using a slider in a dashboard, the `HTML` code is as follow:

```
<!-- Range Slider Start -->
<label id="labelslider" for="slider">Selecteer Range</label> <!-- Range -->
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />
<output for="slider" id="range">0</output>
<!-- END Range Slider -->
```

I'm using the following bit of `JavaScript` to get the output of the sliders value:

```
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.querySelector('#range').value = vol;
}
```

This works great, but the output value is always at the beginning of the slider, i want to move the value of the output as the slider is being moved from left to right.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net to clear the exact picture you have currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the value you whant to change it is the innerHTML, and have in minde that oninput is not supported in IE10 so use onchange insted. I have also changed your picker to getElementById() like this:

```js
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.getElementById('range').innerHTML = vol;
}
```

```html
<label id="labelslider" for="slider">Selecteer Range</label> <!-- Range -->
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10" onchange="outputUpdate(value)" />
<output for="slider" id="range">0</output>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on oninput regarding IE10!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a simple math here,

```
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.querySelector('#range').value = -(vol - 100);
}
```

And set your slider `value` as `100` initially in your html. Now you can move your slider from `right` to `left` with the values ranges from 0 to 100 in the same direction.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bjpcc4Ls/)

Comment: Thanks, but that i got working. I want the posistion of the outputted value to be under the position of the slider position